# isn't 10 000 the limits of queries in Google Search Engine?

Tags: python, google-custom-search

```
import pandas as pd
products = pd.read_csv('products_asin.csv') #DataFrame with 1000 codes(asin) of Amazon products

from urllib import request
from apiclient.discovery import build
#Google Custom Search Definitions

search = build('customsearch','v1',developerKey=api_key).cse()

 #downloading all images

error_list= []
for asin in products['asin']:
    try:
        #searching
        query = search.list(q=asin, cx=search_id,searchType='image').execute()
        url = query['items'][0]['link']
        #saving in jpg file
        with open('imgs/'+asin+'.jpg','wb') as file:
            file.write( request.urlopen(url).read()   )
    except:
        #logs if the query got error
        print('error in '+asin)
        error_list.append(asin)
```

After almost 100 queries, the log that i created starts to giving me error in all queries, and, when i try any other query in the same day, it returns me HTTP error. The page of https://cse.google.com/ says that we can use 10 000 searches per day, why can i query only 100? And, if the limit is 100, where can i pay to get more queries?

Comment: There is a developer console in Google API website where you can track the number of times you sent query. Check if the limit was reached. There is also the factor that it could be a limit of number of queries per second.

Comment: [This page](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) states, `"Custom Search JSON API provides 100 search queries per day for free. If you need more, you may sign up for billing in the API Console. Additional requests cost $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k queries per day."` That is probably the daily limit that you hit. Although the actual http error code would help see the reason.